# How to serve static files from file system with Quarkus

Tags: quarkus

I am running a Quarkus application server (Serving REST via HTTP) behind an ngnix web server. Now I want to serve static content (Flutter web-app) from file system from with the same base url. Letting ngnix serve it would do it but I would like to use the access control configured in Quarkus application.properties for web app part, too.

Shouldn't it be possible to let my Quarkus server also serve the static stuff?

As server and app are in separate repos and maintained separately, both parts should be deployable independently.

I would expect this to be a common issue but can't find a simple solution.

Any hint?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want a Quarkus application to be able to serve static file from a specific directory on the file system?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I am open to other suggestions but this looks like the way to solve the problem.
I also thought about adding the static files on-the-fly to the already deployed jar. Would be more like a workaround.

Comment: You'd have to include the resources in the produced JAR. Quarkus doesn't provide any configuration for using a random file system directory to serve static files.

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage [Quarkus Reactive Routes](https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-routes) with something like:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class StaticAuthenticatedDeclarativeRoute {

    @Route(path = "/auth-static/*", methods = Route.HttpMethod.GET)
    @Authenticated
    void secureStatic(RoutingContext rc) {
        StaticHandler.create(FileSystemAccess.RELATIVE, "content/").handle(rc);
    }

}
```

and consider the path can also be absolute using `FileSystemAccess.ROOT`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem (but not the requirement to serve from filesystem).

What you can do according to the [Quarkus documentation - HTTP Reference](https://quarkus.io/guides/http-reference#serving-static-resources):

Put your static web content into `META-INF/resources` directory of your application.

Then build your quarkus application and deploy it.